Best input method to specify travel time: Slider or something else?
I am creating a feature for contractors to specify how far they are willing to travel for assignments (e.g., “How long are you willing to travel?”). The travel range is between 30 minutes up to 4 hours.
I'm thinking about using a slider or numeric input (one for hours, one for minutes).
Any suggestions of other input methods or examples taken from other websites would be very appreciated.

I would choose a selector with one of the variables, for example "minutes", a label when those minutes reach a key figure and another label when they reach the limits.


Nice! That felt very intuitive.
